# Distinct over multiple columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to apply distinct on multiple rows in SQL Server? The query that I have tried below does not work on SQL Server.

```
select distinct(column1, column2), column3 
from table_name
```

Comment: Hello Sayalee, welcome on Stack Overflow, to help you please provide some data and the expected output.

Comment: There is no need for the brackets, `select distinct column1, column2, column3 from table_name` this query will only return distinct values.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is always applied to the **entire row** - not just one or two columns ....

Answer (score 3):

`select distinct` applies to all columns in the row.  So, you can do:

```
select distinct col1, col2, col3
from t;
```

If you only want `col1` and `col2` to be distinct, then `group by` works:

```
select col1, col2, min(col3)
from t
group by col1, col2;
```

Or if you want random rows, you can use `row_number()`.  For instance:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by newid()) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

A clever version of this doesn't require a subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by col1, col2 order by newid());
```